# Designing Bandpass Filter Using filterDesigner

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to design a FIR bandpass filter to reject middle frequencies of a signal using fiterDesigner tool. However I have never used this before so I had some troubles but I know the basic idea of the bandpass filter.

[image: image1]

and here is my `fftshift(fft(signal))` output (only `fs/2` part):

[image: image2]

My sampling frequency value is `44100`. I need to reject middle frequency. So I set up filter design as above picture. (Filter Order should be minimum order).

When I try to design this filter, I got:

> `Fpass2` must be less than `22050` (half of sampling frequency).

I could not get why this happened. How can I design a FIR bandpass filter to reject the middle frequency of a signal?

Comment: Hi Sardar, have you found the solution, and have you looked in my suggestion?

Comment: @VladP No I could not find yet, I just leave a comment to your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In digital signal processing, the rule of thumb is that any processing frequency must be less than the half of the sampling frequency. Look a the Nyquist criterion somewhere, for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem.
As you can see, there is a good portion of math involved. In a nutshell, if the frequency is more than the half of the sampling frequency, there will be overlapping of the spectrum around half. The solution is to either increase sampling frequency, which I probably not possible, or to reduce the filter design frequencies.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I changed the values like this: fpass1 = 3000, fstop1 = 4000, fstop2 = 18000, fpass2 = 19000. So I increase the range of frequencies to kill them but again there were no change in "fftshift(fft(signal))" output. What inputs should I give to kill middle frequencies?

Comment: Try to control the order by increasing it, instead of using minimum order. Filters of higher order may achieve steeper characteristics of the filter.